# Non-negativity of the Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, heat-equation

Let there be a decomposition $φ(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\sin{nx}$ on the segment $[0,π]$, and on our segment $φ(x)≥0$. How do I prove that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne^{-n^2} \sin{nx}$ converges to a non-negative function on $[0, π]$?

Let me give a solution for the case of a continuous piecewise smooth function $φ(x)$. Consider a boundary value problem:

$$u_t=u_{xx},\,0\lt x \lt \pi, \, t\gt 0$$

$$u(x,0)=φ(x)$$

$$u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0.$$

According to the maximum principle for the heat equation, the continuous solution $u(x,t)$ reaches its maximum and minimum values only at the boundary of the considered region, i.e. or at $x=0$, or at $x=π$, or at $t=0$.

It remains to write down the solution to the problem by the method of separation of variables(due to the conditions on $φ(x)$, this solution will be continuous): $u(x,t)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne^{-n^2t} \sin{nx}$, where $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\sin{nx}=φ(x)$ and substitute $t=1$.

The task seemed to me beautiful. It was not possible to find any "direct" solution (even in the class of continuous functions). If someone suggests one, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: What are you assuming about $\varphi$ for the general case? Is it in $L^2$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, the general case is $L^2$ when the maximum principle does not work.

Comment: What exactly is the question?  The first paragraph asks if the solution is non-negative; the last paragraph seems to ask why the solution is given by the indicated Fourier series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon$.

Since $\phi\in L^2$ and continuous functions are dense in $L^2$, there exists $f\in C([0,\pi])$ such that $\|f-\phi\|_2\leq\epsilon$.  Moreover, since $\phi\geq0$, the function $f^+=\max{(f,0)}$ must be *closer* to $\phi$…thus we may assume $f\geq0$ as well.  (Likewise for vanishing at $\{0,\pi\}$.)

Write $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{d_n\sin{nx}}$ formally; then $d_n=\langle f,\sin{(n(\cdot))}\rangle$ and $c_n=\langle\phi,\sin{(n(\cdot))}\rangle$.  By Cauchy-Schwarz, \begin{align*}
|d_n-c_n|&=|\langle f-\phi,\sin{(n(\cdot))}\rangle \\
&\leq\|f-\phi\|_2\|\sin{(n(\cdot))}\|_2 \\
&\leq\epsilon\cdot1
\end{align*}  (I may have dropped a constant or two.)

In fact, the series for $\phi$ converges a.e. by Carleson's theorem.  So \begin{align*}
\phi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{c_ne^{-n^2}\sin{nx}}&\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\begin{cases}
d_n-\epsilon&\sin{nx}\geq0\\
d_n+\epsilon&\sin{nx}<0
\end{cases}\right)e^{-n^2}\sin{nx}} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{d_ne^{-n^2}\sin{nx}}-\epsilon\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-n^2}|\sin{nx}|}
\end{align*}  Call the first term $u$ and the second $\epsilon\theta$.  By the argument you give in the problem, $u\geq0$.  Taking $\epsilon\to0^+$, it suffices to find a uniform bound on $\theta$.

But $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-n^2}|\sin{nx}|}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-n^2}}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-n}}=\frac{1}{e-1}$$  So we're done.

Comment: Did you "show" that all c(n)>=0? This is not necessarily true, take at least φ(x)=x ...
Most likely, the error lies in this phrase "...each d(n)>=0 ...", because this also does not follow from anywhere.

Comment: @ReneMorningstar: Sorry; I lost track of what problem I was solving midway through.  (Don't answer problems late at night, kids!)  It should be fixed now.

Comment: I checked your answer and I can say that the argument is already better than the previous one and even give you +1, but the main estimate (after the word "Thus") is incorrect, since sin nx takes values of different signs, so the inequality $\ge$ does not have to be preserved when multiplied by it.

Comment: @ReneMorningstar: Huh?  I'm trying to bound it from above, not below.  $\theta$ is an error term, so the worst-case scenario is when all of its summands are of the same sign.

Comment: @JacobManaker rene is talking about the inequality after "thus", not after "but". rene is correct. your solution is wrong

Comment: @mathworker21: Oh!  Thanks.  It doesn't really affect the solution, but I've fixed it all the same.

Comment: @JacobManaker sorry, but why can you write $f(x) = \sum_n d_n \sin(nx)$?

Comment: @mathworker21: [Carleson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem).  It only needs to hold a.e., since the end result ($\phi\geq0$) is about $L^2$ functions.

Comment: @JacobManaker Thanks. But now I'm getting confused. It seems like your wording/logic is off. Shouldn't you say "Let $d_n = \langle f,\sin(n\cdot)\rangle$. Then $f(x) = \sum_n d_n\sin(nx)$ almost everywhere"?

Comment: @Jacob Manaker I didn't say anything about theta. I'm talking about the very first estimate. For example, if it is known that $a≥b$, then how do you know that $a\sin{nx}≥b\sin{nx}$?

Comment: @ReneMorningstar: Yes, mathworker21 pointed that out to me.

Comment: @mathworker21: OK sure.  I've changed the wording to make it clear where I need to work formally and where I don't.

Comment: @Jacob Manager yes, now it's good. Just about f - continuity is not enough for the function to equal the Fourier series, but this is already my fault. To apply the maximum principle, one initially had to ask for not only continuity, but also piecewise smoothness. Fortunately, smooth compactly supported functions are also dense in L2, and the solution remains the same. Carleson's theorem is useless - Bessel's inequality is sufficient. If you don't mind waiting a little, maybe someone else's solution will appear :D

Comment: @ReneMorningstar: Oh, totally not.  Way too many MSE questions have only one answer.

Comment: Fortunately, smooth finite functions are also dense in L2, and the solution remains the same.*  - amendment

Answer (score 2):

Here a probabilistic take on the question.

Let $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be standard Brownian motion on $[0,\pi]$, with both endpoints absorbing barriers. Let $T:=\inf\{t>0: B_t \in\{0,\pi\}\}$. Using a little martingale theory you can show that
$$
e^{-n^2t/2}\sin(nx)=E^x[\sin(nB_t); t<T], \qquad 0\le x\le\pi, t>0, n=1,2,\ldots.
$$
(The notation $E^x$ indicates expectation under the condition that $B_0=x$.)
Multiply by $c_n$, sum over $n\ge 1$, and specialize to $t=2$. We can bring the summation inside the expectation on the right because $\sin$ is bounded and $e^{-n^2}$ decays rapidly. There results
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2}c_n\sin(nx)=E^x\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\sin(nB_2); 2<T\right]=E^x[\varphi(B_2); 2<T].
$$
Because $\varphi\ge 0$ by hypothesis, the sum on the left is also non-negative. (N.B. The function $(x,t)\mapsto E^x[\varphi(B_t); t<T]$ is the solution to a modified form of your your boundary value problem — replace $u_{xx}$ with ${1\over 2}u_{xx}$.)

It may be worth noting that the second expectation on the right in the last display is a smooth function of $x\in(0,\pi)$ for any bounded measurable $\varphi$.